# Parsing Weatherbug's XML data in C#

Tags: c#, xml

For the past few days I've been trying to figure out how to parse Weatherbug's Live Weather RSS feed in C#. I'm not the most experienced in XML, so I'm looking for a little direction.

Here's a generalized version of the data I'm working with just as an example.

```xml
<rss xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" version="2.0">
     <channel>
          <title>Observations from Chicago, IL - USA</title>
          <description>Weatherbug</description>
          <language>en-us</language>
          <lastBuildDate>Tue, 04 Feb 2014 23:00:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
          <ttl>60</ttl>
          <aws:weather xmlns:aws="http://www.aws.com/aws">
               <aws:api version="2.0"/>
               <aws:ob>
                    <aws:temp units="&deg;F">22.8</aws:temp>
                    <aws:sunset>
                         <aws:hour number="5" hour-24="17"/>
                         <aws:minute number="09"/>
                    </aws:sunset>
               </aws:ob>
          </aws:weather>
     </channel>
</rss>
```

I want to get the temperature and the sunset into temporary variables so that I could use them. I just can't get a working portion of code that can extract the information I need.

Here's the code I've managed to put together. I get the title just fine, but I can't seem to get the temperature or the sunset.

```cs
XmlNode channel = doc.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");

string title = channel.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("aws", "http://www.aws.com/aws");
XmlNode aws = channel.SelectSingleNode("aws:weather", man);  

label13.Text += title;

string tempVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob").SelectSingleNode("aws:temp").InnerText;  
string sunsetVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob").SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset").SelectSingleNode("aws:hour").Attributes["number"].Value + ":" + aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob").SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset").SelectSingleNode("aws:minute").Attributes["number"].Value;         
label13.Text += tempVal;
label13.Text += sunsetVal;
```

Comment: what values do you get for temperature or sunset?

Comment: @TanujWadhwa Originally I didn't get anything at all, the value was null for both. With har07's answer and MarcinJuraszek's updated answer, I was able to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `XmlNamespaceManager` in every `SelectSingleNode` that uses prefix in its XPath string :

```
string tempVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                        .SelectSingleNode("aws:temp", man)
                        .InnerText;
string sunsetVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                        .SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset", man)
                        .SelectSingleNode("aws:hour", man).Attributes["number"].Value 
                    + ":" + 
                    aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                        .SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset", man)
                        .SelectSingleNode("aws:minute", man)
                        .Attributes["number"].Value;
```

Above codes can be simplified by combining chaining `SelectSingleNode` calls as single Xpath expression, for example :

```
string tempVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob/aws:temp", man).InnerText;
string sunsetVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob/aws:sunset/aws:hour", man).Attributes["number"].Value 
                    + ":" + 
                   aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob/aws:sunset/aws:minute", man).Attributes["number"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good with `XmlDocument`, so I can't help you fixing your current solution, but I can give you working one, using LINQ to XML. It's more modern way to handle XML files in .NET and I would say that's the recommended one.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");
var aws = XNamespace.Get("http://www.aws.com/aws");

var channel = xDoc.Root.Element("channel");
var title = (string)channel.Element("title");

var weather = channel.Element(aws + "weather");

var tempElement = weather.Element(aws + "ob").Element(aws + "temp");
var tempValue = (string)tempElement;
var tempUnits = (string)tempElement.Attribute("units");

var sunsetElement = weather.Element(aws + "ob").Element(aws + "sunset");
var sunsetHour = (int)sunsetElement.Element(aws + "hour").Attribute("number");
var sunsetMinute = (int)sunsetElement.Element(aws + "minute").Attribute("number");
```

The only problem it has, it cannot parse your XML because of `&deg;` entity, which is not standardized. But the same issue occurs with `XmlDocument`, so I don't think it changes anything.

> Additional information: Reference to undeclared entity 'deg'. Line 11, position 39.

***Update***

OK, I see where is the problem with your current solution. You're not passing namespace manager `nas` into your XPath queries. Try that:

```
string tempVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                    .SelectSingleNode("aws:temp", man).InnerText;

string sunsetVal = aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                      .SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset", man)
                      .SelectSingleNode("aws:hour", man)
                      .Attributes["number"].Value
                   + ":" +
                   aws.SelectSingleNode("aws:ob", man)
                      .SelectSingleNode("aws:sunset", man)
                      .SelectSingleNode("aws:minute", man)
                      .Attributes["number"].Value;
```

Comment: Your updated answer worked for me, like @har07's answer, you both hit the nail on the head.